# Fingerprint recognition not working with new screen guard on OnePlus 9R

Tags: hardware, touchscreen, fingerprint

I have a OnePlus 9R Android phone and the screen guard cracked when the phone fell.

I tried to buy a replacement screen guard from one plus but the official site shows it as out of stock for the last three months.

I fitted my phone with a non-oneplus screen protector but now the fingerprint recognition won't work.

I even tried deleting the prints and adding new ones but no luck.

Any ideas or workarounds? Should I just try another brand for the screen guard?

Comment: this vid shows how to increase sensitivity with screen protectors. https://youtu.be/NsYVu9lmYk4